# SUBSTR() function in IF statement

Tags: mysql, substring

```
+----+---------------+-------+
| id | link          | title |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 1  | v_156399569   | abc   |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 2  | y_u0inSsAoFU4 | xyz   |
+----+---------------+-------+
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', 
                'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='substr(link,3), 
                'https://vimeo.com/'substr(link,3)) as link, `title`
FROM `video`
WHERE `reg_id` = '101'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| link                                      | title |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=156399569 | abc   |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| https://vimeo.com/u0inSsAoFU4             | xyz   |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
```

In the above query I can't use `substr(link,3)` function when expression is `true`. After `v=` I wanna get a sub string value of `link` column in the table.

The above query fire some error. So please help me to solve this issue. Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is basically how to concatenate 2 strings?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes. The below answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to add this two strings on this way:

> ```
> create table video(link varchar(200), title varchar(200));
> ```

> ```
> insert into video values ('y_LjhCEhWiKXk', 'Bruno Mars - Just The Way You Are [OFFICIAL VIDEO]');
> ```

> ```
> select title,
>        if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', 
>           concat('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', substr(link,3)), 
>           concat('https://vimeo.com/', substr(link,3))) as link
> from   video;
> ```
>
> ```
> title                                              | link                                       
> :------------------------------------------------- | :------------------------------------------
> Bruno Mars - Just The Way You Are [OFFICIAL VIDEO] | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjhCEhWiKXk
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2d9e57674c4201812efcb64228637fb5)*

Answer (score 0):

This is just a modification of [McNets solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/180211/66829) a bit simplified and switching to Standard SQL syntax when possible (`substr` -> `substring`,  and `if` -> `case`) also supported by MySQL (only `||` instead of `concat` doesn't exist). Maybe more characters to key in, but easier to port to other DBMSes:

```
select title,
   concat(case substring(link from 1 for 2)
             when 'y_' then 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
             when 'v_' then 'https://vimeo.com/'
                  -- easy to extend for more sites
             else 'unknown site ' -- just in case
          end
         ,substring(link from 3)) as link
from video
```

Of course this would be simpler if the `link` column was properly normalized.

Comment: `||` can be used too, by changing mode: [`PIPES_AT_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: go, *ANSI mode*, go :-)